# Correct AC input wiring for electronic door lock PSU

Tags: power-supply, ac, wiring

I have a small PSU that outputs 12v DC for use with electronic door locks, but I'm a bit uncertain about the AC input. From the diagram it looks like there is two AC live wires, and a single earth. Does this mean I can use either red wire for the neutral? Ie, Live (1), Neutral (2), Earth (3)? Or is this circuit not earthed (!) and neutral is the green/yellow pin (3)?

[image: Photo of board]
[image: Image of wiring diagram supplied with unit]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Green/Yellow wire is always the protective earth/ground wire, it must never be used for anything else, so it is not Neutral.

It says in that document that the other two wires are mains input. You can use 100 to 240 volts mains. So yes, one of them is the Live and the other can be the Neutral. Pick any way you like.

But you must connect the earth/ground, so if you are wiring this to a mains plug, you must use a 3-prong mains plug with earth/ground pin, and it must be connected to a mains outlet that provides the earth/ground so it must not be connected to a 2-prong outlet.

Comment: Thanks @Justme, in the UK they're all 3-pin so no worries there. I figured as much, but the lack of a negative terminal on either the board or the diagram gave me doubts.

Comment: AC has no terminal that could be called as negative. In the UK mains socket you simply have Live, Neutral and Earth/Ground. But that is not always the case in other places. I've learnt that in the UK, construction sites can use 110 VAC mains for safety reasons, but it comes from a 110 VAC transformer where the center tap is used as the Earth/Ground referenced Neutral, so you have two Live phase wires with 55 VAC on each, and thus 110 VAC between the two Live wires. So sometimes there is a Live and a Neutral, sometimes two Live wires. The power supply does not care.